Query database Firebase based on name category
I have read many posts but none can be good for me. My database:
    services
    
    -Nw9TVp-6EjCI-xXWO3r
    category: "veterinarian"
    name: "Veterinary aaaaabb"
    
    -Nw9UmVy3RgDb_wMeVBi
    category: "groomer"
    name: "Center jkhkjhkjh"

-NwJK914TuItRsxDWD2X
category: "groomer"
    name: "Angel jkh"

my query is this but the data doesn't come out:
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
let ref = rootRef.child("services").child("$servicesId").queryEqual(toValue: "groomer", childKey: "category")

How can I get all the nodes that have the value "groomer"?

Try this rootRef.child("service").queryOrdered(byChild: "category").queryEqual(toValue: "groomer") query.

When you use this query:
rootRef.child("services").child("$servicesId").queryEqual(toValue: "groomer", childKey: "category")

It means that you try to query all elements that exist under:
services/$servicesId

Which will not return expected elements because, under such a node, there are only two fields present. If you want to get the elements under the services node where the category field holds a specific value, for example, groomer, you have to use the following query:
rootRef.child("service").queryOrdered(byChild: "category").queryEqual(toValue: "groomer")


Raja Kishan had already helped me, thanks to you too ;-)
